# How can I test if an object inherits or is a member of a generic class?

Tags: swift

Suppose I have a class `class C<T>`.

I want to write a function `f(_ a: Any) -> Bool`, which returns true when `a` is a member of class inheriting from `C` (or is a `C` itself). I don't care about the specialization: passing `C<Int>`, `C<Double>`, `C<Whatever>` should all return `true`.

It *seems* like I should be able to just write `a is C` or `a as? C != nil` as the body of that function, however, these both don't compile in a playground; swiftc complains that "generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred in cast to 'C<_>'". If I write `f` inside of `C` as an instance method, `C` is implicitly `C<T>`, and so writing `let c = C<Int>(); c.f(C<Double>())` returns `false`.

I can work around this by writing a protocol `P`, which `C` conforms to, and then test for that but I don't consider that a good solution; it's just a hack.

Is there any way to do this?

Here's all the code I wrote to try this:

```
class C<T> {
  func test(_ a: Any) -> (Bool, Bool) {
    return (type(of: a) == C.self, a is C)
  }
}

class D: C<Double> { }

let d = D()

func f(_ a: Any) -> Bool {
  return a is C // generic parameter 'T' could not be inferred in cast to 'C<_>'
}

d.test(C<Int>()) // false, false

// bad solution

protocol P { }

extension C: P { }

d is P // true
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think a language feature exists for you to do this, because it's not useful to just know that an object is a subclass of, or `C` itself, without knowing the generic type parameters.

I mean, what are you gonna do after knowing that, yes, `someObj` is indeed of type `C<Something>`, but not what `Something` is? You can't do anything with `someObject`. You can't cast it so you can't access any members of it.

Swift's generics is very *very* strict, unlike Java, who just throws generic types out of the window at runtime...

If you insist that you want to do this, your only option is to use the hack you mentioned.

Or, if you just want to check whether `a` is `C` itself, not any of its subclasses, you can use this (just for fun):

```
func f(a: Any) -> Bool {
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "C<.+>")
    let typeString = String(describing: type(of: a))
    let range = NSRange(location: 0, length: typeString.characters.count)
    let matchRange = regex.rangeOfFirstMatch(in: typeString, range: range)
    return range.toRange() == matchRange.toRange()
}
```

Comment: To your point about usefulness; just because I don't know the type `someObject` is specialized on doesn't mean that the knowledge that it inherits from `C` is useless; just knowing that some object (my superview in a view hierarchy, for example) is of type `C` might mean that certain invariants about the views below it hold, for example.

Comment: @BenPious if you are in a view hierarchy, just use `tag`s. By checking whether a superview's tag is some value, you can know whether that is the view you're looking for. Are they not enough?

Comment: Anyone could pick the same tag as I did for some view. Furthermore, now users of `C` have to know that they can't set the tags of instances of types that inherit from `C`, or it'll break an implementation detail of `C`. To be clear, being a member of `C` is enough to know that the invariants hold; it's not some specific instance. So I want to be able to test that; and it seems like I can't do that without erasing the generic with `P` which `C` (and only `C`) conforms to, as I said at the end of my question.

Answer (score 0):

See how dump is declared

```
func dump<T, TargetStream where TargetStream : TextOutputStream>(_ value: T, to target: inout TargetStream, name: String? = default, indent: Int = default, maxDepth: Int = default, maxItems: Int = default) -> T
```

And check what it produces

```
class C<T>{}
class D:C<Double>{}

let c = C<Void>()
let d = D()

dump(c)
dump(d)
```

Yes, dump is part of Swift's standard library ... which use reflection (objects mirror) to produce its result.

UPDATE

I created cli project named **dumptest** with one file main.swift

```
//
//  main.swift
//  dumptest
//

class C<T>{}
class D:C<Double>{}
class E:D{}

let c = C<Void>()
let d = D()
let e = E()

var tc = ""
var td = ""
var te = ""

dump(c, to: &tc)
dump(d, to: &td)
dump(e, to: &te)

print("type info about c:", tc)
print("type info about d:", td)
print("type info about e:", te)
```

running it the program reported

```
type info about c: - dumptest.C<()> #0

type info about d: - dumptest.D #0
  - super: dumptest.C<Swift.Double>

type info about e: - dumptest.E #0
  - super: dumptest.D
    - super: dumptest.C<Swift.Double>

Program ended with exit code: 0
```

For parsing String variables check stackoverflow, or ask a new question ...

lets have

```
import Cocoa

let v = NSView()
dump(v)
```

dump value v and we have

```
- <NSView: 0x100a022a0> #0
  - super: NSResponder
    - super: NSObject
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

If you need something "more complex", you can play with
[Mirror](http://swiftdoc.org/v3.1/type/Mirror/)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see how this answers the question. Can you explain a bit more about how implementing the `f` function is related to `dump`?

Comment: @Sweeper dump is easiest way how to use mirroring in swift. If you will run the snippet, you will see, that the result is there in human readable form and it is easy to recognize what OP is looking for. Few lines of code can make the result to be computer readable :-)

Comment: `dump` prints to standard out; it's actually useless if you want to test this at runtime. Even if it did give you a string to parse, it's not obvious to me at all how to demangle "_TtGC14__lldb_expr_281CSi_", which is the output for `dump(d)`

Comment: @BenPious i updated my answer, I hope it helps you. Using dump helps you to check all super classes, what is not possible with Sweeper's example.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a protocol that specifies what you are expecting for this test is not at all a hack; it's exactly how Swift should be used. (What you are asking is indeed impossible, and purposefully so.) Write that protocol, but not as an empty hack; fill it with what you are testing for and then view it as a beautiful part of your code's structure!